# JQuery How to return correct dates when using Moment JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have some blog posts where I want to display the date which the post was published. For that I want to use `momentjs`. So the HTML looks like this

```
<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-06-20"></span>

<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-07-01"></span>

<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-08-23"></span>
```

My JS looks like this:

```
$(".published_date").each(function() {
    let publishDate = $(this).attr("data-publish-date");
    let formattedDate = moment(publishDate, "d. MMMM YYYY").format(
        "d. MMMM YYYY"
    );
    $(this).text(formattedDate);
});
```

This returns wrong dates

```
4. June 2019
1. July 2019
5. August 2019
```

I have no clue why this happens so can someone help me out?

Comment: It looks like you didn't check the moment docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input is in ISO 8601 recognized format you can use [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and in [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) use uppercase `D` is *Day of Month* instead of lowercase `d` that stands for *Day of Week*

Here a live sample:

```js
$(".published_date").each(function() {
    let publishDate = $(this).attr("data-publish-date");
    let formattedDate = moment(publishDate).format(
        "D. MMMM YYYY"
    );
    $(this).text(formattedDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-06-20"></span>

<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-07-01"></span>

<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-08-23"></span>
```

Comment: Yes, this solved it! Thanks a million! :-) Can't believe I missed that :D

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You've **explicitly** given it a format to parse with (`"d. MMMM YYYY"`), but that format doesn't remotely match the data you're providing it (`"2019-06-20"`, etc.).
2. You're using `d`, not `D`, when formatting. Per [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), `d` is the day of the *week*, not the day of the month.

If you make the formats correct, it should work:

```
let formattedDate = moment(publishDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").format(
    "D. MMMM YYYY"
);
```

Live Example:

```js
$(".published_date").each(function() {
    let publishDate = $(this).attr("data-publish-date");
    let formattedDate = moment(publishDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").format(
        "D. MMMM YYYY"
    );
    $(this).text(formattedDate);
});
```

```html
<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-06-20"></span>

<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-07-01"></span>

<span class="published_date" data-publish-date="2019-08-23"></span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```